# SSL Certificate Issue with PingFederate for Mobile Server

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-8, pingfederate

We are facing an issue w.r.t to the SSL Certificates.

We have 3 hosts on which SSL Certificates have been applied.

Web (IIS 8), Mobile (IIS 8), PingFederate

The SSL is working fine in case of Web.
Web Workflow:
Web(https) > PingFederate(https) > ADFS(https)
After the request gets successfully authenticated by ADFS, our request takes the following route:
ADFS(https) > PingFederate(https) > Web(https).

In case of Mobile, we are getting an error at the following stage:
Mobile(https) > PingFederate(https) > ADFS(https)
After the request gets successfully authenticated by ADFS, our request takes the following route:
ADFS(https) > PingFederate (https)

As soon as the request gets out of ADFS, the following error message is displayed:
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be https://pingfederate.com which could put your confidential information at risk
When we try to access the Mobile Server via Internet Explorer from our laptop, following error message is displayed:
This organization's certificate has been revoked.
Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.

We are trying to understand if there are Certificate Issues with PingFederate(https), then we should be getting these issues while going from Web(https) > PingFederate(https) > ADFS(https) and also while going from Mobile(https) > PingFederate(https) > ADFS(https).
But we are getting certificate issues only while return from ADFS(https) > PingFederate (https) and that too in case of mobile server only.

Can anyone please suggest what we should do.
Thank You

Comment: Just to confirm, Sugam, is the connection between ADFS (IdP) and PingFed (SP) the *same* in both instances (web flow and mobile flow)?

Comment: Hi Andrew, the issue was resolved. The port ":9031" was missing from the SAML Assertion Consumer Endpoint at the ADFS end. As soon as it was added, it started working for us. We have set up different IdP Connections for Web and Mobile. Thanks